# Keras functional API: Can training be prevented branch-wise on a branching model?

Tags: keras

I'm training a somewhat complicated model using Keras that involves multiple branches. Because of the structure of the problem, it doesn't make sense to train these pieces separately, but I don't want to apply the loss function for the main branch of the network to another branch that merges with the main branch (That branch has its own loss function and outputs). I was wondering if there's any way to accomplish this within the Functional API.

Here's a toy model definition that highlights the basic problem I'm running into. The layers themselves don't matter, what's important is the structure of the model:

```py
    #Utility for subtracting some tensors
    def diff(two_tensors):
        x, y = two_tensors
        return x - y

    #Two inputs
    in_1 = Input((128,))
    in_2 = Input((128,))

    #Main branch: Does something to the first input
    branch_1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(in_1)
    branch_1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(branch_1)

    #Auxilliary classifier definition:
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    #This model asserts a confidence, and we'll use a sigmoid to actually classify

    #The classifier takes the second input and the result of the main branch
    pred_a = classifier(branch_1)
    pred_b = classifier(in_2)
    class_out = Activation('sigmoid')
    class_a = class_out(pred_a)
    class_b = class_out(pred_b)

    #We calculate the difference between these two confidences in a lambda
    pred_diff = Lambda(diff)([pred_a, pred_b])

    #The main model uses this difference for another classification
    branch_join = concatenate([pred_diff, branch_1], axis=-1)
    main_output = Dense(20, activation='softmax')(branch_join)

    #The model outputs the aux classifier's choices and the main prediction
    model = Model(inputs=[in_1, in_2], outputs=[main_output, class_a, class_b])
    losses = { 'main_output': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
             , 'class_a': 'binary_crossentropy'
             , 'class_b': 'binary_crossentropy'
             }
```

I want to train the classifier in the middle of this model only on its classification accuracy for its two inputs. However, since it's hooked up to the main branch, I think the loss from the main output will also propagate through those layers. In many similar cases (like simple GANs), the answer would be to train the classifier separately and freeze the classifier when training the end-to-end system. However, that won't work for my use case, and I'm wondering if I can stop the loss from main_output from backpropagating into the classifier model, while still training it on its own outputs.

Comment: can you set the trainable=False for those layers and train the rest of the model ?

Comment: No, because then those layers wouldn't be training at all. I want to train them on the classification loss (from outputs "class_a" and "class_b") without training them on the main branch's loss function (from output "main_output")

Comment: will creating a custom loss function or a custom callback in keras help ?

Comment: Can't you train it in two steps? First you train the classifier and only afterwards you set the weights to be non trainable and trains whichever part of the network that comes after

Comment: As I mentioned before, that's the approach I would normally take, but won't work for the problem I'm trying to solve. Is there no way to change which connections are trainable, rather than which layers?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan I'm not sure how it would help, can you elaborate?